# DAX formula working in Power BI but not on Power Pivot

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

The following DAX formula works on Power BI but not on Power Pivot (don't show error but blank cells) using the same exact data model (checked this many times).

It's used in a calculated column.

```
Actual Units SO = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( COM_SellOut[QuantitySold] ),
    FILTER ( COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[Date] >= TMK_Promotion[FromDate] ),
    FILTER ( COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[Date] <= TMK_Promotion[ToDate] ),
    FILTER ( COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[ProductCode] = TMK_Promotion[ProductCode] ),
    FILTER ( COM_Customers, COM_Customers[id] = TMK_Promotion[Customer] )
)
```

A little context: this formula iterates a promotion table and calculates the units sold of a given product, in a given customer between a given period. Works flawlessly in PowerBI but not on PowerPivot.

Any ideas of what could be causing the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason for using 4 separate `FILTER` functions rather than either nesting them or concatenating the conditions in to one criterion using `&&` in one `FILTER`?

Comment: No, just did this as a first version but can implement the && in one FILTER, no problem.

Comment: I'd start there, and you may need to add a `RELATED` to each reference to the other table (presumably TMK_Promotion)

Comment: Ok I'll try that first and come back with the results. 

If the goal is to modify the filter context for each row on the iteration, why `REPLACE` would be needed if i'm not looking for a value in the other tables?

Comment: It's a calculated column, so it's row context, not filter context and you are trying to relate it to a value in another table as far as I can see. Which table is this calculation in?

Comment: Inside the same TMK_Promotion table. The goal of this formula is to get the total unit sales of a given product (ProductCode) in a given customer (Customer) in a given period (From/To Date) for each row of the TMK_Promotion table. So the objective is to modify the filter context via context transition and bring the sum of the filtered COM_SellOut table, which contains the sales of each product, each day, on each customer.

Comment: And it's a calculated column, not a measure?

Comment: Correct. The table is very small (1k rows and less than 15 columns) so there's little performance impact, and also that value is used later for another calculations.

Comment: Then I'm fairly sure you need RELATED in there when referring to the other table.

Comment: can you post images of the data models, both in PBI and power pivot?

Comment: @Rory modified the `FILTER` statement as suggested but didn't work. Same result.

@RADO here's the image: https://imgur.com/a/W5AhO5l . It's the same for both PBI and PP, so I suspect it's more syntax related.

Comment: I suspect that your data models are not the same. Please post the PBI data model diagram too, at last to eliminate this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Power Pivot and Power BI use the same engine, so the same version DAX works in both applications. Are you using a colon (Actual Units SO **:=**) in front of your equal sign (no space). In Power Pivot it's a must whereas in Power BI it's optional. I see in your example there is no colon, so your DAX measure won't work in Power Pivot. It's a syntax issue not a model or DAX issue.

```html
Actual Units SO :=    
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( COM_SellOut[QuantitySold] ),
        FILTER ( COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[Date] >= TMK_Promotion[FromDate] ),
        FILTER ( COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[Date] <= TMK_Promotion[ToDate] ),
        FILTER ( COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[ProductCode] = TMK_Promotion[ProductCode] ),
        FILTER ( COM_Customers, COM_Customers[id] = TMK_Promotion[Customer] )
    )
```

Comment: This formula is a calculated column.I too suspect it's more related to a syntax issue more than a model one, because it's the same on both, but only works on PBI.

Comment: Fransico. It does not matter. You will need a colon for calc columns too. Could you please give it a try.. .add the colon and let us know if it works. And if it works, please mark this question an answered. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get a better performance by using logical and in one filter rather than nesting your filters :

```css
Actual Units SO = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( COM_SellOut[QuantitySold] ),
    FILTER ( COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[Date] >= TMK_Promotion[FromDate] 
        && COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[Date] <= TMK_Promotion[ToDate]
        && COM_SellOut, COM_SellOut[ProductCode] = TMK_Promotion[ProductCode]
        &&  COM_Customers, COM_Customers[id] = TMK_Promotion[Customer]
      )   
)
```